# Linear Regression Model based on Log-Cosh Loss Function in R

Tags: r, machine-learning, regression

I have read about loss functions theoretically and also how to build regression models based on them in R.

I can apply all of the regression models based on different loss functions in R programming except for Log-Cosh Loss Function.

For example, I would like to build a linear regression model on 5-folds subsets of the [***DATA***](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Superconductivty+Data), and then extract the coefficients and calculate the individuals and the aggregated variance as follows.

```
data = read.csv("train.csv") # "critical_temp" is the dependent variable. 
data_nom_df=as.data.frame(scale(data))#Normalization   
#Cross Validation
set.seed(12345)
k = 5 
folds <- createFolds(data_nom_df$critical_temp, k = k, list = TRUE, returnTrain = TRUE)
## Ordinary Least Square regression

#block A
lm = list()
for (i in 1:k) {
  lm[[i]] = lm(critical_temp~ ., 
               data = data_nom_df[folds[[i]],])
}

#block B
lm_coef = list()
lm_coef_var = list()
for(j in 1:(lm[[1]]$coefficients %>% length())){
  for(i in 1:k){
    lm_coef[[i]] = lm[[i]]$coefficients[j] 
    lm_coef_var[[j]] = lm_coef %>% unlist() %>% var()
  } 
}

#block C
lm_var = unlist(lm_coef_var)
lm_df = cbind(coefficients = lm[[1]]$coefficients %>% names() %>% as.data.frame()
              , variance = lm_var %>% as.data.frame()) 
colnames(lm_df) = c("coefficients", "variance_lm")
lm_df

#block D
lm_var_sum = sum(lm_var)
lm_var_sum
```

The same for the rest of the regression models. However, I do not find any code or package to apply a regression model based on Log-Cosh Loss Function in R.

Could you please guide me to any source that would help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done from first principles.  Also note the existence of the `logcosh` function in the limma package which could be used in place of `log(cosh(.))` if you have numeric difficulties.

```
f <- function(b) with(cars, sum(log(cosh(dist - b[1] - b[2] * speed))))
fm0 <- lm(dist ~ speed, cars)
res <- optim(coef(fm0), f, method = "BFGS")
str(res)
## List of 5
##  $ par        : Named num [1:2] -12.82 3.47
##   ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:2] "(Intercept)" "speed"
##  $ value      : num 532
##  $ counts     : Named int [1:2] 28 10
##   ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:2] "function" "gradient"
##  $ convergence: int 0
##  $ message    : NULL
```

### Graphics

```
# the black line is the ordinary least squares regression line and 
# the red line is the log cosh regression line
plot(cars)
abline(fm0)
yfit <- res$par[1] + res$par[2] * cars$speed
lines(cars$speed, yfit, col = "red")
```

[image: screenshot]

### ADDED

Note that the optimization can also be written like this which may be useful if you have many independent variables.

```
fm0 <- lm(dist ~ speed, cars)
X <- model.matrix(fm0)
f <- function(b) with(cars, sum(log(cosh(dist - X %*% b))))
res <- optim(coef(fm0), f, method = "BFGS")
res
```

giving:

```
$par
(Intercept)       speed 
 -12.816190    3.469536 

$value
[1] 531.5872

$counts
function gradient 
      28       10 

$convergence
[1] 0

$message
NULL
```

Comment: thanks. 1- I can not find a package called "limma". 2- Does your code for building a regression model based on Log-Cosh Loss Function? because I got strange results such as "function gradient", "convergence" and "message".

Comment: limma is in bioconductor althoughyou may not need it. We did not use it in the code above. If you want it google *R logcosh* .  From within R try `?optim` for more info on the output of `optim`..

Comment: @jeza in case of the OLS linear regression, the loss function can be minimized analytically, and you get analytic expressions for the slope and the intercept. You can also use numerical optimization, and you should be able to match the output of `lm`. Most loss functions cannot be optimized analytically. You get messages about convergence, gradients, etc because they are essential parameters of any optimization algorithm. Other functions aside from `optim` can be used, e.g., `stats::nlm`.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck, many thanks, how can we run the code if we have multiple independent variables? Suppose we have a dataset with 12 columns and 1599 rows.

Comment: Modify theobjective  function `f` appropriately.  e.g. `f <- function(b) sum(log(cosh(y - b[1]  - b[2] * x[, 1] - b[3] * x[, 2])))`

Comment: @G.Grothendieck, thanks but this will be too much if I have 80 variables such the dataset I am working on.

Comment: Use matrix multiplication: `f <- function(b) sum(log(cosh(y - X %*% b)))`

Comment: @G.Grothendieck, I got `Error in fn(par, ...) : object 'y' not found`. I edited my question.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck, after some modification, I got `Error in xdata %*% b: requires numeric/complex matrix/vector arguments`

Comment: Just showing an error message is not enough to diagnose a problem in R but I have inserted an ADDED section which shows how to use the model matrix with the example in the question.